# Get max calls by a person Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say, I have number `A` and they call several people `B`

```
A   B

123 987
123 987
123 124
435 567
435 789
653 876
653 876
999 654
999 654
999 654
999 123
```

I want to find to whom the person in `A` has called maximum times and also the number of times.

**OUTPUT:**

```
A   B           Count
123 987         2
435 567 or789   1
653 876         2
999 654         3
```

How one can think of it is,

```
A      B
123    987 2
       124 1


435    567 1
       789 1

653    876 2

999    654 3
       123 1
```

Can somebody help me out on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```py
# count the unique values in rows
df.value_counts(['A','B']).sort_index()
```

```
A    B  
123  124    1
     987    2
435  567    1
     789    1
653  876    2
999  123    1
     654    3
dtype: int64
```

To get the highest values for each unique A:

```py
v = df.value_counts(['A','B'])
# remove duplicated rows
v[~v.reset_index(level=0).duplicated('A').values]
```

```
A    B  
999  654    3
123  987    2
653  876    2
435  567    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) which by default sorting values, so get first rows per `A` by [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df = df.groupby('A')['B'].value_counts().groupby(level=0).head(1).reset_index(name='Count')
print (df)
     A    B  Count
0  123  987      2
1  435  567      1
2  653  876      2
3  999  654      3
```

Another idea:

```
df = df.value_counts(['A','B']).reset_index(name='Count').drop_duplicates('A')
print (df)
     A    B  Count
0  999  654      3
1  123  987      2
2  653  876      2
4  435  567      1
```